# Unexpected 40ms ping

Tags: java, sockets, ping

I'm experiencing a weird issue, and I can't figure out what is occurring.
So basically, when I try to make a simple connection between a server and a client with an exchange of a float number (with DataInputStream and DataOutputStream), it seems that there is a fixed ping limit, exactly 40ms on three different computers with openjdk.

Furthermore, I tried to change the way I send the float number with:

```
outs.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(3.14f).array(), 0, 4);
```

which is supposed to do the same thing as:

```
outs.writeFloat(3.14f);
```

and this odd ping limit surprisingly vanished!

Maybe I am doing something wrong with the following code:

**client side**

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class client {

    private Socket sock;
    private DataOutputStream outs;
    private DataInputStream ins;

    public client() throws IOException{
        byte c;

        sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),9998); 
        outs = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ins = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        do{
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            /* here is the thing */
            //outs.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(3.14f).array(), 0, 4); // either this outs
            outs.writeFloat(3.14f); // or this one

            outs.flush();
            c = ins.readByte();
            long stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("elapsed time: "+(stop-start)+"ms");

        }while(c == (byte) 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
          client client = new client();
        } catch(SocketException e){
            System.out.println("Socket disconnected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

}
```

**server**

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class server extends Thread{

    private DataOutputStream outs;
    private DataInputStream ins;

    public server(Socket sock) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("client connected");
        outs = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        ins = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true){
                float f = ins.readFloat();
                System.out.println("value: "+f);
                outs.writeByte((byte) 1);
                outs.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("client disconnected");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(9998);

            while(true){
                server server = new server(serverSock.accept());
                server.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

which gives me (on localhost) with the usual writeFloat:

> elapsed time: 40ms

else with write():

> elapsed time: 0ms

***Edit :***

Apparently, it seems that [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286621/mike) answer solved the issue! No more 40ms latency with writeFloat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows? Try to increase the number of bytes you send. There is (or was) a limit within the Windows TCP/IP stack, which waits for an amount of time the get get more bytes to get  a full Package to send.

Comment: Hmm, not really: only tested on ubuntu, ubuntu, and debian... Anyway, I thought about a kind of buffer waiting to be filled before being sent, but I am using the flush method!
Or maybe, it is deeper in the tcp/ip protocol, but why would it works with the other write() trick?

Comment: Try setting tcp nodelay socket option.